# Writing If loop in R

Tags: r

I want write if loop in R in correct way when I apply this code I get an error (Error: unexpected 'else' in "else")

```
if(shapiro.test(X)$p.value>=0.05 && t.test(X, alternative = "two.sided")$p.value>=0.05){
  rp<-1}
else if (shapiro.test(X)$p.value>=0.05 && t.test(X, alternative = "two.sided")$p.value<0.05){
  rp<-2}
else if(shapiro.test(X)$p.value<0.05 && wilcox.test(X, mu = 0, alternative = "two.sided")$p.value>=0.05){
  rp<-3}
else if(shapiro.test(X)$p.value<0.05 && wilcox.test(X, mu = 0, alternative = "two.sided")$p.value<0.05)
{rp<-4}
```

Comment: This isn't a loop. It's a series of conditional statements. It's also inefficient. You only need to write each test once. You could get `rp` without any `if` statements at all by using conversion of TRUE/FALSE to 1/0 - such as doing `rp <- 2 * as.numeric(shapiro.test(X)$p.value < 0.05) +  as.numeric(t.test(X, alternative = "two.sided")$p.value < 0.05) + 1`

Comment: @AllanCameron could you please explain it more

Comment: Sure, it's a bit involved for the comments so I have expanded this as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't a loop. It's a series of conditional statements. It's also inefficient. You only need to write each test once. You could get `rp` without any if statements at all by considering the following:

1. The expression `shapiro.test(X)$p.value < 0.05`  will evaluate to either `TRUE` or `FALSE`
2. This means that `as.numeric(shapiro.test(X)$p.value < 0.05)` will be 1 if the test is significant and 0 otherwise.
3. Similarly, `as.numeric(t.test(X, alternative = "two.sided")$p.value < 0.05)` will return 1 if significant and 0  otherwise.
4. If we multiply `as.numeric(shapiro.test(X)$p.value < 0.05)` by two and add it to the result of `as.numeric(t.test(X, alternative = "two.sided")$p.value < 0.05)`, we will get a number between 0 and 3 which represents 4 possibilities:

- 0 means neither test was significant
- 1 means only the t-test was significant
- 2 means only the shapiro test was significant
- 3 means that both tests were significant

5. If we add one to the above numbers, we get the desired value of `rp`.

Therefore, your code simplifies to:

```r
rp <- 2 * as.numeric(shapiro.test(X)$p.value < 0.05) +  
          as.numeric(t.test(X, alternative = "two.sided")$p.value < 0.05) + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, just a rearrangement of brackets. This syntax works. But is verbose.

```
X <- rnorm(100, 3, 1)

if (shapiro.test(X)$p.value>=0.05 && t.test(X, alternative = "two.sided")$p.value>=0.05){ 
  rp <- 1
} else if (shapiro.test(X)$p.value>=0.05 && t.test(X, alternative = "two.sided")$p.value<0.05){
  rp <- 2 
} else if (shapiro.test(X)$p.value<0.05 && wilcox.test(X, mu = 0, alternative = "two.sided")$p.value>=0.05){
  rp <- 3
} else if (shapiro.test(X)$p.value<0.05 && wilcox.test(X, mu = 0, alternative = "two.sided")$p.value<0.05){
  rp <- 4
}
```